# Unexpected behavior accessing objects from different threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, ninject

I'm currently seeing some off behaviors as I'm working on a multithreaded windows service. The issue that I'm having is that some objects appear to be resetting when accessed from different threads.

Let me demonstrate with some code (simplified to explain the problem)....

First, I have a class that launches threads based on methods in another class (using Ninject to get the classes) and  then later stops them:

```
public class ContainerService : ServiceBase
{    
    private IEnumerable<IRunnableBatch> _services;

    public void start()
    {
        _services = ServiceContainer.SvcContainer.Kernel.GetAll<IRunnableBatch>();
        foreach (IRunnableBatch s in _services)
        {
            s.run();
        }
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        foreach (IRunnableBatch s in _services)
        {
            s.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, within the run() method of an IRunnableBatch class I have something like this:

```
public class Batch : IRunnableBatch
{
    //this class is used for starting and stopping threads as well as tracking
    //threads to restart them should the stop
    protected IWatchdog _watchdog; 

    ... code ommitted for brevity but the watchdog class is injected by Ninject
         in the constructor ...

    public void run()
    {
        _watchdog.startThreads(this);
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        _watchdog.stopThreads();
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the Watchdog class:

```
public class Watchdog : IWatchdog
{

    private ILog _logger;
    private Dictionary<int, MethodInfo> _batches = new Dictionary<int, MethodInfo>();
    private Dictionary<int, Thread> _threads = new Dictionary<int, Thread>();
    private IRunnableBatch _service;
    private Thread _watcher;
    private Dictionary<int, ThreadFailure> _failureCounts = new Dictionary<int, ThreadFailure>();
    private bool _runWatchdog = true;

    #region IWatchdog Members

    /**
     *  This function will scan an IRunnableService for the custom attribute
     *  "BatchAttribute" and use that to determine what methods to run when 
     *  a batch needs to be launched
     */
    public void startThreads(IRunnableBatch s)
    {
        _service = s;

        //scan service for runnable methods
        Type t = s.GetType();
        MethodInfo[] methods = t.GetMethods();
        foreach (MethodInfo m in methods)
        {
            object[] attrs = m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BatchAttribute), true);
            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length >= 1)
            {
                BatchAttribute b = attrs[0] as BatchAttribute;
                _batches.Add(b.Batch_Number, m);
            }
        }

        //loop through and see if the batches need to run
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, MethodInfo> kvp in _batches)
        {
            startThread(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }

        //check if the watcher thread is running. If not, start it
        if (_watcher == null || !_watcher.IsAlive)
        {
            _watcher = new Thread(new ThreadStart(watch));
            _watcher.Start();
            _logger.Info("Watcher thread started.");
        }
    }

    private void startThread(int key, MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (_service.shouldBatchRun(key))
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => method.Invoke(_service, null)));
            try
            {
                thread.Start();
                _logger.Info("Batch " + key + " (" + method.Name + ") has been started.");
                if (_threads.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    _threads[key] = thread;
                }
                else
                {
                    _threads.Add(key, thread);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //mark this as the first problem starting the thread.
                if (ex is System.Threading.ThreadStateException || ex is System.OutOfMemoryException)
                {
                    _logger.Warn("Unable to start thread: " + method.Name, ex);
                    ThreadFailure tf = new ThreadFailure();
                    tf.Count = 1;
                    _failureCounts.Add(key, tf);
                }
                else { throw; }
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopThreads()
    {
        _logger.Info("stopThreads called");
        //stop the watcher thread first
        if (_watcher != null && _watcher.IsAlive)
        {
            _logger.Info("Stopping watcher thread.");
            _runWatchdog = false;
            _watcher.Join();
            _logger.Info("Watcher thread stopped.");
        }

        int stoppedCount = 0;

        _logger.Info("There are " + _threads.Count + " batches to stop.");

        while (stoppedCount < _threads.Count)
        {
            ArrayList stopped = new ArrayList();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Thread> kvp in _threads)
            {
                if (kvp.Value.IsAlive)
                {
                    _service.stopBatch(kvp.Key);
                    kvp.Value.Join(); //wait for thread to terminate
                    _logger.Info("Batch " + kvp.Key.ToString() + " stopped");
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.Info("Batch " + kvp.Key + " (" + _batches[kvp.Key].Name + ") has been stopped");
                    stoppedCount++;
                    stopped.Add(kvp.Key);
                }
            }

            foreach (int n in stopped)
            {
                _threads.Remove(n);
            }
        }
    }

    public void watch()
    {

        int numIntervals = 15 * 12; //15 minutes in 5 second intervals 

        while (_runWatchdog)
        {
            //cycle through the batches and check the matched threads.
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, MethodInfo> kvp in _batches)
            {
                //if they are not running 
                if (!_threads[kvp.Key].IsAlive)
                {
                    //mark the thread failure and then try again.
                    ThreadFailure tf;
                    if (_failureCounts.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
                    {
                        tf = _failureCounts[kvp.Key];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tf = new ThreadFailure();
                    }
                    tf.Count++;

                    if (tf.Count >= 8)
                    {
                        //log an error as we've been trying to start this thread for 2 hours now
                        _logger.Error("Unable to start the thread: " + kvp.Value.Name + " ***** NOT TRYING AGAIN UNTIL SERVICE RESTART");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _logger.Warn("Thread (" + kvp.Value.Name + ") found stopped... RESTARTING");
                        startThread(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
            //sleep 15 minutes and repeat.
            _logger.Info("*** Watcher sleeping for 15 minutes");
            for (int i = 1; i <= numIntervals; i++)
            {
                if (!_runWatchdog) 
                    break;
                Thread.Sleep(5000); //sleep for 5 seconds
            }
            _logger.Info("*** Watcher woke up.");
        }

        _logger.Info("Watcher thread stopping.");
    }

    public void setLogger(ILog l)
    {
        _logger = l;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So, the main program calls ContainerService.start() which calls the IRunnableBatch.run(), which calls IWatchdog.startThreads().  The startThreads() method locates and launches all of the threads it finds, then launches a thread to watch the others in case they die for some reason. Then the functions exit all the way back up the the main function.

Now, a service simply waits for the service manager to call OnStop() but for testing purposes I have the main thread sleep for 1 minute then call ContainerService.stop().

After all of that explanation, I now get to the issue.... whew!!

When the main thread calls stop(), and the stop() method calls IRunnableBatch.stop(), if I have a breakpoint there and examine the _watchdog variable I see that all of it's associated member variables are set back to their initial values (no threads, no watcher thread, no batches, nothing...).

Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: Thread micro-management :((

Comment: 1. I don't see any locking in your code. Why would you think it is thread-safe? 2. Don't use ArrayList unless you're stuck with .NET 1.1.

Comment: Are you sure the threads were actually created? Add more tracing to see what was really executed.

Comment: How is Ninject configured to activate your Watchdog; my guess is that you're wanting to share the same object, but it's configured as "transient," so each dependent is getting its own distinct watchdog object.

Comment: @Jacob: Ninject is configured to use transients, yes. Though I did this purposely because I wanted each IRunnableBatch instance to have its own copy of watchdog and Ninject was giving them all the same instance. Each IRunnableBatch then stores the watchdog instance it's given so I would expect that any changes made on it would persist properly as the watchdog is only accessed from inside the IRunnableBatch.

Comment: @AloisKraus: Yes, all of the threads are getting created. I've debugged through the start of each of them and I have quite a bit of logging going on that is working fine. The issue only happens when I go to stop the threads.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: 1) Where would you expect locking? The watchdog objects are only accessed from within their IRunnableBatch instances. It's just that the process for stopping them is kicked off from another thread (to allow the threads to cleanup properly).  2) Please excuse my ignorance but what's wrong with an ArrayList?

Comment: The `ArrayList` class is obsolete, along with things like `HashTable`. These classes were in the Framework on Day 1 because Generics had not yet been implemented. There's no reason to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem. Read https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection, and you'll see that GetAll returns an enumerable that activates your objects as you iterate, not a list. Therefore, in ContainerService.start, your runnable batch objects are created, and in stop, a whole new set of objects are created.

Try adding a .ToList() after your call to GetAll, or change your Ninject config so that your runnables are not transient.